# Cant make bootstrap popover work with slim

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover, slim-lang

I am trying to implement bootstrap popover in my slim view but so far It didnt work :[image]

Here's the problematic part of my slim view :

```
 td = tournament.subscriptions.count
 td data: {container: body, html: true, content: hello, toggle: popover, placement: top, trigger: hover, title: dispo}
    = tournament.subscriptions.where(status: "confirmed").count
```

I think I respected the syntax but it still doesnt work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use a hash to define attributes for the `td` tag.

This should work for you:

```
td data-container='body' data-html='true' data-content='hello' data-toggle='popover' data-placement='top' data-trigger='hover' title='dispo'
```

A couple of things to note for the modified `td` line:

1. All of the attributes except for `title` are data attributes, so I added "data" to them.
2. I was assuming that "hello" and "dispo" were supposed to be strings so I've got them quoted. If those are actually variables, just use `"#{dispo}"` and `"#{hello}"` instead.

And in case you aren't doing this already, be sure to fire the `popover` method to get your popovers to actually working:

```
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```